# "IP-Config: No response after X seconds - giving up" from initramfs

Tags: networking, 18.04, initramfs

I've setup remote unlocking of a LUKS partition using Dropbear SSH in the initramfs:
https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/

The problem I get is that on one particular Ubuntu 18.04 machine, a virtual private server running on KVM virt hardware, the DHCP inside the initramfs doesn't pickup an IP address:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ip=off"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ip=none"
```

F2 to save

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot the pc